# Importing lwc from managed package

Tags: managed-package, lightning-web-components

I'm currently developing a managed package, with a LWC.

From another package, I want to import this managed package in order to access some of the exported elements, like the class or some constants.

I'm getting an error saying that the module does not exist, I've tried using

```js
import { CONSTANT, Class} from 'plhd/placeholder';
import { CONSTANT, Class} from '@plhd/placeholder';
```

PROJECT PATH                                             ERROR
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────

force-app/main/default/lwc/searchSource/searchSource.js  No MODULE named placeholder found

Comment: Are you sure those components are global?

Comment: As far as I know, you cant mark a LWC as global. Based on the documentation this could be accomplished https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_components_namespace

Comment: You are right, that seems a limitation, you can set `isExposed` but based on the following documentation components from different namespace are not accessible: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags

Comment: Was there ever a resolution found here? I'm experiencing the same issue, and I don't have a way to check the XML files of the components I want to import from a managed package.

Comment: Currently there is no way to import/use lwc from managed packages from a lwc. If you want to use one, you should refactor your parent component into an aura component and reference from the LWC from the managed package. I talk to the people at Salesforce and they told me that is not planned to allow this, so don't expect it

Comment: Any updates here ?