# Can I use an externally namespaced component in my namespace?

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package, namespace

I want to experiment with [nebula logger](https://github.com/jongpie/NebulaLogger/tree/main) in my namespaced scratch org. After installing the package as a managed package and updating an LWC to use it, I get the error:

`No MODULE named Nebula:logger found`

I have confirmed the namespace is `Nebula` and I am accessing an [exported function](https://github.com/jongpie/NebulaLogger/blob/main/docs/lightning-components/Logger.md#createLogger) via

`import { createLogger } from 'Nebula/logger';`

Is my component unable to see this because it belongs to a separate namespace? Or because I have not declared it as a dependency?

To be able to test this do I need to clone the source and deploy it through sfdx/mdapi and not install it as a package?

I'm just not sure what "rule" I'm breaking, or if Salesforce even allows packages in different namespaces to depend on each other.

Edit: Referencing `Nebula.logger` through apex deploys just fine, so I think I'm not referencing the namespace correctly in my LWC.

Comment: I don't think this is possible at the moment.  See also:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286604/importing-lwc-from-managed-package

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/security-lwsec-locker-comparison.html), this supports cross name space component use. Specifically,

> Your Lightning web components can import components or modules from other namespaces and use them via composition or extension.

The details on how to enable Lightning Web Security are available here:
[Enable Lightning Web Security in an Org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/security-lwsec-enable.html)